# Why regex comparison is faster exactly comparison?

Tags: node.js

My API have to compare a large item in array to find only one item from that array. I am using regex to compare and it's too slow, I guess regex comparison is cause and refactor code to use exactly comparison and result is bad than before refactor.

```
Array sample: id was compiled of attribute 
const items = [{
  id: 'a:b:c:d',
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
 }, 
 ...
];

// Current code
const item = items.find((i) => new Regex('a:b:c:.*').test(i.id))

// After refactor code
const item = items.find((i) => {
  const isMatchedAttA = i.a === 'a';
  const isMatchedAttB = i.b === 'b';
  const isMatchedAttC = i.c === 'c';

  return isMatchedAttA && isMatchedAttB && isMatchedAttC;
})
```

Comment: Both arrays and regexes are not the right tool for such a task if we need it to be performant. You should look into a different data-structure such as a [prefix tree (trie)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) which may be a better choice assuming you should match only the prefix of a string.

Comment: @NirAlfasi Array is a sample, because it's result of database query

Comment: In that case you can also improve the results by updating the query to fetch a more targeted set of results (modify the query). If you need to do it only once per query-results there's not much you can do in the code to improve it: maybe use [String.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of regex-matching. But if you need to run it multiple times against the same set of results, then it may be beneficial to construct a Trie (because we can re-use it). I hope it makes sense!

Comment: database collection is too large, each query to database is slow too so I don't want query many times to database. But thanks, I will research about trie

Comment: As I wrote: if you need to query multiple times for different strings, it may be worth to consider doing "pre-processing" by constructing all the words in the DB into a Trie and keep it in-memory, then every such transaction will be very quick!